# Are private properties of public classes secure in a DLL

Tags: c#, security, dll

I understand the difference between public and private for accessibility and general programming practice.  I am asking more specifically about the security of this in a DLL.

The DLL looks like this...

```
public static class OrphanAnnieDecoderRing
    {
        private const string _secretCode = "Drink More Ovaltine";

        private int OvaltineDrinkCount = 0;

        public void DrinkOvaltine() => OvaltineDrinkCount += 1;

        public string RevealSecret
        {
          get
            {
              if (OvaltineDrinkCount >= 500)
                {
                  return _secretCode;
                }
              else
                {
                  return "Unable to reveal secret!";
                }
           } 
        }
    }
```

Are my _secretCode and the OvaltineDrinkCount properties secure from visibility or manipulation by anyone accessing the DLL (aside from the conditional allowance once they have met certain criteria)?  I know DLL files can open up some security problems, I wasn't sure if private properties or private constants were among those problems to be aware of.

Comment: wait, you have to drink more ovaltine to reveal the secret, which is to drink more ovaltine.  Is this a pyramid scheme

Comment: no, it's A Christmas Story :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Access-Modifiers are used to restrict access of members to callers of your class.
This is useful to enforce encapsulation, one of the primary goals introduced with object oriented programming OOP ( hiding implementation details, etc.).

When you compile your code to a DLL, it is translated to Intermediate Language (IL) in an Assembly (which technically has little to do with classic unmanaged(Win32 Dynamic Link Libraries), which at runtime gets compiled to machine code on the target machine (via Just-In-Time Compiler, JIT).

The IL however, can easily be "reverse-engineered" using tools like [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/), so literally everyone with access to your assembly can "read" the secret.

(To go further, even private readonly fields can be modified from outside the class using reflection, but that is a topic on it´s own).

Comment: Further to this excellent answer, const field values are stored in the assembly manifest, so you don't even have to fully decompile the assembly.

Comment: @earloc Thank you for the concise and complete answer!  Is there any way you would recommend for me to hide the secret in the code?  Or is this something that will need to be otherwise obfuscated?

Comment: depends on the kind of secret..what are you trying to hide from us? ;) maybe we could push you in the right direction, if the actual question is a bit mor precise.
Anyway, as long as this "secret" is stored within an assembly, all you can do is to raise the bar for potentially malicious / fraudulent attempts to misuse the secret (e.g. cryptography or obfuscation).
Either way, it (only) reduces the risk - but also the readability of your code.